How can I run MFCC with Librosa on a signal that is not audio?
I'm experimenting with MFCC as a signal processing technique to analyze the results of empirical mode decomposition on the original signal. This, imfs['0'],  is an array of floating point values with shape (165,).
I am new to MFCC so I am unsure about the practicality of this technique, but I would like to obtain some kind of results regardless.
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
imfs = pd.read_csv('/B0005_soh_EMD.csv')
data = pd.read_csv('/feat_B0005.csv')

y = imfs['0'].to_numpy()
#print(y.shape)

mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y,  n_fft = 10)


#print(y.shape)
#print(sr)
#print(mfccs)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(mfccs), 
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('MFCC')
plt.ylabel('MFCC Coefficient')
plt.show()

imfs['0']
Output of code above
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/librosa/feature/spectral.py:2143: UserWarning: Empty filters detected in mel frequency basis. Some channels will produce empty responses. Try increasing your sampling rate (and fmax) or reducing n_mels.
I have been tweaking various parameters of the feature.mfcc() call and display.specshow() but the plot continues to be blank.

Your signal is very short, not best fit for MFCC. Typical audio signals that are analysed using MFCC consist of at least thousands of samples. You have only 165 samples. That causes default paremeters of mfcc function not work for you properly.
Sidenote: MFCC algorithm first divides signal into numerous small windows. What you have is of size of such small window.
That being said, what you can do is decrease drastically hop_length and maybe less drastically other parameters: win_length, n_mels and n_mfcc.
For example: (..., hop_length=4, win_length=64, n_mels=12, n_mfcc=6)
or even (..., hop_length=2, win_length=64, n_mels=12, n_mfcc=6)
I think this should give you some meaningful 2D image.
